# webpack linking console errors to modules not bundle file

Tags: reactjs, debugging, webpack, source-maps

I have a React project and the devtool setting in webpack is set to "source-map". I am also using storybook, now I intentionally provided a wrong type to a prop to my custom component to generate an error in the console. Why the link to my component `DataGridComponent` is not pointing to the error in its module, but to the bundle file?

[image]